# Error installing with pip

Tags: python, installation, pandas, pip

Trying to uninstall a package installed with pip, I uninstall some and now pip don't work. I try to install pandas:

```
[sudo] pip install pandas
```

And this is the error:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pandas in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pandas)
Downloading/unpacking pytz (from pandas)
Downloading pytz-2013b.zip (535kB): 535kB downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package pytz
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zip_safe'
  warnings.warn(msg)
usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: -c --help-commands
   or: -c cmd --help

error: invalid command 'egg_info'
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zip_safe'

warnings.warn(msg)

usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]

 or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]

 or: -c --help-commands

 or: -c cmd --help

error: invalid command 'egg_info'

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-root/pytz
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

I have Linux Mint Mate 15. How I can resolve this??

Answer (score 5):

Update your `setuptools` installation with `pip install -U setuptools`.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing distribute with `pip install distribute`.

Comment: Try installing pandas again with `pip install pandas`. The command `egg_info` should be included with distribute.

Comment: I would try reinstalling distribute and then pip, but I can't really provide much more help than that.